# Prove: $4^{2k+1}>1 \cdot 3 \cdot \dots \cdot (2k+1)$ where $k$ is a positive integer

Tags: inequality, factorial, integers

Prove: $$4^{2k+1}>1 \cdot 3 \cdot \dots \cdot (2k+1)$$ where $k$ is a positive integer.

The difference is very large but I cannot find any way to prove it.

Comment: Do you know factorials ? If you do, multiply the rhs by $2.4.6...(2)$, put the same in a denominator which needs to be simplified.

Comment: Are you asking for the largest possible $k$? If so, please re-word your Q. If $f(k)=4^{2k+1}/(1.3...2k+1)$ then $f(k+1)/f(k)=16/(2k+3)$ so $\lim_{k\to \infty}f(k)=0$.

Comment: As explained in my answer, the inequality is true only if reversed and for $k \ge 19$.

Comment: Looking at your activity on MSE, I note that so far you have asked 11 questions but accepted no answer. Please note that this attitude is discouraged here, and if you do not show appreciation of the work and time that people put into answering your questions for free, you will discover that they will stop helping you. Please review the received answers and whenever you find a good one, do not hesitate to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't true. Indeed, the ratio $\frac{4^{2k+1}}{1\cdot 3\cdot...\cdot(2k+1)}$ tends to zero (while if your inequality was true, it would be bounded below by $1$).

To see this, let $a_k=\frac{4^{2k+1}}{1\cdot 3\cdot...\cdot(2k+1)}$. It's then easy to see that $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=\frac{16}{2k+3}$, which is less than $\frac{1}{2}$ for $k\geq 15$. So we have for $k\geq 15$:

$$a_k=a_{15}\cdot\frac{a_{16}}{a_{15}}\cdot\frac{a_{17}}{a_{16}}\cdot...\cdot\frac{a_k}{a_{k-1}}<a_{15}\cdot\frac{1}{2^{k-15}}$$

which clearly tends to zero.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you wrote in the right hand side is the semifactorial $(2k+1)!!=\prod_{i\le 2k+1, i\equiv 2k+1p\mod{2}}i$. It turns our that
$$
\forall i=1,\ldots,k, 2i+1>2i \implies (2k+1)!=(2k+1)!!(2k)!!<(2k+1)!!^2
$$
Therefore for all $k>64$
$$
(2k+1)!!>\sqrt{(2k+1)!}>\sqrt{63!\cdot 64^{2k+1-63}}>c\cdot 8^k
$$
for a positive constant $c$. Therefore $(2k+1)!!>4^{2k+1}$ whenever $k$ is sufficiently large.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is mistaken: the inequality should have been reversed. Let us prove then that $4^{2k+1} < 1 \cdot 3 \cdot \dots \cdot (2k+1)$ for $k \ge 19$ by induction.

Let us verify it for $k=19$: $4^{39} = 302231454903657293676544 < 319830986772877770815625 = 1 \cdot 3 \cdot \dots \cdot 37 \cdot 39$.

Assume the statement true for $k$ and let us prove it for $k+1$:

$$4^{2(k+1)+1} = 4^{2k+1} \cdot 16 < 1 \cdot 3 \cdot \dots \cdot (2k+1) \cdot 16 < 1 \cdot 3 \cdot \dots \cdot (2k+1) (2k+3)$$

because clearly $16 < 2k+3$ whenever $k \ge 19$.

(Note that the given inequality is not true for $0 \le k \le 18$.)